# Django Rest Framework MySQL Tables renamed/add prefix

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I'm beginner in Django Rest Framework, and today I have a problem with models and `MySQL` dabase.

I have a MySQL table like this:
[Mysql View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTdIH.png)

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models


class Reservation(models.Model):
    reservations = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    done = models.BooleanField()
```

**Structure of Catalogs:**

[Structure of Catalogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCLvm.png)

**Settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',

]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'testsite',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'innodb',                   # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'webroot',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),                  # Not used with sqlite3.
         
    'HOST': 'xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
    'static'
]
```

Why when I migrate data to the dabase, something adds a prefix to table name like: `testsite_`

Conclusion:

I want to create models.py and migrate data to mysql datebase without this prefix `testsite_` , how it was in first image : inndb.testsite_reservation

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.db_table)

> Django automatically derives the name of the database table from the
>   name of your model class and the app that contains it. A model’s
>   database table name is constructed by joining the model’s “app label”
>   – the name you used in `manage.py startapp` – to the model’s class name,
>   with an underscore between them.
>
> To override the database table name, use the `db_table` parameter in
>   `class Meta`.

So for your example you could write

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    reservations = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    done = models.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        db_table='testsite_reservation'
```

Comment: This works fine and also this resolve another my problem that I not mentioned in this post. Thanks!